# How do I strip unwanted characters and strings?

Tags: python, regex

I want to strip all unwanted [A-Z] characters (among others) except for certain words. For example, we have the following string:

`get 5 and 9`

I would like to get rid of all the words that are not 'and' or 'or' so the end result is `5 and 9`. I also want to strip out all characters not being part of '[0-9].+-*()<>\s' too.

The current regular expression works for stripping out all characters but I don't want it to strip out 'and'. In this example, the result would be '5 9'.

```
string = 'get 5 and 9'
pattern = re.compile(r'[^0-9\.\+\-\/\*\(\)<>\s)]')
string = re.sub(pattern, '', string)
```

I am not an expert on regular expressions and struggle to find a solution for this. I am kind of lost.

Is this possible or should I look for other solutions?

Comment: Try `" ".join(re.findall(r'\b(?:or|and)\b|[-0-9.+/*()<>]', s))`, see https://ideone.com/D3QVse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revised version

```
import re

test = "get 6 AND 9 or 3 for 6"
keywords = ['and', 'or']
print(' '.join(t for t in test.split() if t.lower() in keywords or t.isdigit()))

$ python test.py
6 AND 9 or 3 6
```

This rejects words containing and and or,

Previous version.
This is a pretty simple solution I think, but unfortunately did not work as it picks up 'and' and 'or' in longer words.

```
import re

test = "get 6 AND 9 or 3"
pattern=re.compile("(?i)(and|or|\d|\s)")
result = re.findall(pattern, test)
print(''.join(result).strip())

$ python test.py
6 AND 9 or 3
```

Words are case-insensitive because of (?i). Spaces are retained with \s but stripped from beginning and end in the print statement. Digits are retained through \d. The parentheses around and|or|\d|\s are the bits of the string that are found through findall which generates a list of what has been found, then they are joined back together in the print function.

Comment: Does not work if longer words contain `or` or `and`. Maybe add word boundary `\b`?

Comment: True that. It will capture any words containing and and or as well. I don't see a straightforward way to avoid it, as adding delimiters to either end of the words will cause it to miss the following word or number. Maybe the list based one is best. I'll add that.

Comment: The regex version worked for me. I am using `pattern = re.compile(r"(?i)(\band\b|\bor\b|\d|\s)")`, I've added the `r''`.

Answer (score 1):

An approach without using regular expression

```py
input = 'get 5 and 9'

accept_list = ['and', 'or']

output = []
for x in input.split():
    try :
        output.append(str(int(x)))
    except :
        if x in accept_list:
            output.append(x)

print (' '.join(output))
```

Output

> 5 and 9